# Should I unsubscribe from Firestore in an App.vue destruction lifecycle?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently developing an app with Vue.js and Firebase database.
I am listening to real-time changes of one of the database documents, at the App.vue level.

In a child component, I would typically unsubscribe from the database in the `beforeDestroy()` Vue.js lifecycle.

Is there any point of unscubscribing at the App.vue level?

Thanks!

Comment: Destroying App.vue means the user is leaving your app and the memory for your app will be released, so I don't see the point of unsubscribing at the App.vue level.

Answer (score 1):

If you believe that all subscribes should have matching unsubscribes, for the purpose of code symmetry, and communicating to other readers of your code when the subscription is expected to end, you might choose to add that code.

If your code runs in an environment (perhaps a test environment) that does not fully get destroyed when the lifecycle is complete, then you'd probably want to make sure your app releases its resources correctly.

Or maybe you are just concerned if there is any chance at all a subscription might leak, causing you money over time as it causes reads when those reads will not be used, so you choose to clean up properly just in case.